# How to use sqlalchemy with ThreadPoolExecutor?

Tags: python, sql, sqlite, sqlalchemy, concurrent.futures

I am building an application that needs to write a stream of events to a database which I am doing as follows

```
engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine('sqlite:///data.db'                                  
'check_same_thread=false&timeout=0.001&mode=rwc&nolock=1&cache=shared&uri=true')

async def pull_data():
    while True:
            data = await pull_data()
            df = pd.DataFrame(data)
            df.to_sql('data_db', engine, if_exists='append', index=False)
```

I then need to read from this database in a function that is executed in concurrently via `concurrent.futures ThreadPoolExecutor` in a separate python shell. So shell 1 streams data and builds the database ('`data_db`') and shell 2 executes an function that reads from '`data_db`' across multiple elements (names) concurrently.

```
# function to read data
def df_by_name(name):
    con = engine.connect().execution_options(stream_results=True, check_same_thread=False)
    db_name = "SELECT * FROM" + " " + "data_db" + " " + "WHERE name LIKE" + " " +\
              "'%s'" % str(name + "%") + " " + "ORDER BY timestamp ASC"
    df = pd.read_sql(db_name, con)
    return df 

# main function that is run across names via ThreadPoolExecutor
def main(... name):
    df = df_by_name(name)
```

with this approach I am able to run the application for a small number of names concurrently but when I increase the number of names being run concurrently I run into errors

```
OperationalError: database is locked
```

Clearly there is commenting wrong with the way I am setting up sqlalchemy. If any one can point me in the right direction to solving this challenge Id be very grateful.

Comment: Relevant https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/dialects/sqlite.html#database-locking-behavior-concurrency

Answer (score 1):

SQLite isn't really designed for a high level of concurrency - I think the error means you are writing to the database, which means it is locked while the data get written. The connection isn't being closed in time for the next query to succeed.

There are a few things to try:

- it's possible that configuring a longer timeout for your connections could mitigate, but not solve the problem
- `aiosqlite` is a driver library that I believe has ways to manage the problem (you'd need to install the library and connect to `sqlite+aiosqlite:///data.db`, and there may be some refactoring to do)
- use a different SQL database that can handle your operational requirements, e.g. Postgres